# ExpressJS server is not setting correct headers

Tags: node.js, express, frontend, backend

I have created an ExpressJS server on port 8080 that will be receiving requests from another webapp running on port 8889.    I've set the appropriate headers, but the browser console still gives me the following:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8889' is therefore not allowed access.

The code for the server is written here:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', 8080);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8889");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
     res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
     next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.send(JSON.stringify(json));
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
     var host = 'localhost';
     var port = '8080';
     console.log('Server listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The code for the request is here:

```
function getJSON(callback){
        return http.get({
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 8080,
        }, function (response){
                var body = '';
                response.on('data', function (d) {
                        body += d;
                });
                response.on('end', function(){
                    callback(JSON.parse(body));
            });
    }).on('error', function (err){console.log('couldnt get credentials');});
}
```

A wildcard is clearly not being used.  Can anyone shed light on what's happening?

Comment: I copied your server code and ran it no problem other than defining the variable `json`. When I used jQuery to make the request everything worked fine in Chrome and FF. What library are you using to make the http request on the frontend?

Comment: @Ryan I'm just using the NodeJS library with the http.get.  The exact code to make the request is shown above.

Comment: You are using the NodeJS library in the browser?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I believe so. Or rather, I'm using the http module from NodeJS.  I'm a complete n00b at web development; is using NodeJS incorrect?

Comment: If you have a node server talking to a node server CORS doesn't apply. CORS is only applicable when making an ajax request in the browser to a different domain.

Comment: @Ryan So I shouldn't be getting this warning at all? I am making a request in the browser using the NodeJS module to the ExpressJS server.  The webapp making the request uses a server created through Connect by a gulpfile.

Comment: Seems like it should work then. Dumb question, did you restart the 8080 server after making all your changes?

Comment: @Ryan I would restart it every single time I made changes, but I've managed to fix it by adding the CORS node module.  Thanks for trying to offer help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using the CORS node module found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and it ended up fixing the issue.